# What is the default shell for .sh in AIX?

Tags: shell, shell-script, aix

I am fairly new to AIX machine. We would like to deploy some program into the AIX machine which is yet to come.

We have a short experience in AIX machine and after login using putty, we felt the shell is very weird and some aspects compared to the Red Hat Linux we are using. The backspace is not functional, and some arrow key have weird behaviour too.

Anyway, assume this is a healthy machine, I would like to ask, if we create a .sh file and execute it, what is the default shell for it? And what is the default shell after login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red Hat uses `bash` as its shell; AIX will use a modified commercial-UNIX Bourne Shell or various out-of-date (and buggy) versions of `ksh` depending on version (as of AIX 4, it was either a buggy `ksh88` or a buggy clone thereof).  If you want arrow keys, you will need to run `ksh` or `bash` (and if the `ksh` on that version of AIX is still pre-`ksh93`, arrow keys won't work although <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will).

Backspace not working is a symptom of the `stty` settings being incorrect; Linux generally prefers `DEL` for backspace, but AIX uses the System III/V standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> by default.  Try `stty sane; tset -Q`.  (This may still leave it at `^H`, in which case you'll need `stty erase '^?'`.)  While you're at it, make sure `$TERM` is correct (it should usually be `xterm` or `xterm-color`; if the latter doesn't work, use the former).

Comment: The wiki said that AIX use Korn-Shell, is the wiki too old? "The default shell was Bourne shell up to AIX version 3, but was changed to Korn shell (ksh88) in version 4 in view of XPG4 and POSIX compliance." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX

Comment: You didn't specify which AIX you were using; and at least as of AIX 4.3.3, `sh` was not (or not a normal) `ksh`, and was often buggy; a `bsh` was provided for scripts that broke under `sh`. I presume this was because of contractual requirements to maintain bug-level compatibility in `sh`). You will still need to make sure `$TERM` and the `stty` settings are correct, and arrow keys will *not* work in `ksh88`.

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe it *was* `ksh88` — not `ksh88i`, which is what I have experience with, and was preferred to `ksh88` for good reason.

Comment: We have no idea about the version because the machine is yet to come. Thanks. Can you please edit the asnwer specific to different version of AIXs?

Comment: If it's a new machine it'll probably be AIX 6.1; I don't know anything about the shell there. :(

Comment: I am wondering one thing. If I put a shebang in the shellscript and tell the machine to use bash, will it be independent of the linux version? I supposed every version was shipped with bash shell available.

Answer (score 1):

The default shell in any 5.x -> 6.x version of AIX is ksh.

As of version 6100-04-03-1009 of AIX, ksh is installed running Version M-11/16/88f.

To display the version on your machine, change to vi-mode:

```
# set -o vi
```

Hit Esc, then hit Ctrl-v.

```
# Version M-11/16/88f
```

Comment: Another way to see the version is `echo ${.sh.version}`. Or is that only in ksh93?

Comment: Only in `ksh93` :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support a variety of environments, and you've already written and tested the scripts for bash, you can consider installing the AIX toolbox for Linux.  After that is done, you can add /opt/freeware/bin to everyone's path and use bash.

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/